# jQuery change on click

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to make the "Minus" sign turn back into the plus sign after the user has closed the expendable text.

Here is the code 
HTML

```
<p class="textDropTitle"><span class="textDropLogo"></span>Title</p>
    <div class="textDropSub"><p>This is my text Below</div>
    <p class="textDropTitle"><span class="textDropLogo">+</span>Title</p>
    <div class="textDropSub"><p>This is my text Below</div>
    <p class="textDropTitle"><span class="textDropLogo">+</span>Title</p>
    <div class="textDropSub"><p>This is my text Below</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".textDropSub").hide();

$('.textDropLogo', this).text('+');

$(".textDropTitle").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('fast');
    $('.textDropLogo', this).text('-');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple using a *Conditional Ternary Operator* `(?:)`

```
$(".textDropTitle").click(function() {

    $(this).next().toggle('fast');

    var $el = $('.textDropLogo', this);
    $el.text( $el.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+' );

});
```

> [condition] ? [if is true] : [if is false] ;

<kbd>**[READ MORE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**</kbd>

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for the fast response. Will vote up as soon as I can